# Increased color banding on converting color space using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I converted an image to HSV using  `imghsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, COLOR_BGR2HSV)`. But when I convert this image back to the original colorspace using `imgback = cv2.cvtColor(imghsv, COLOR_HSV2BGR)`, the quality of the image is not the same and there is visible color banding. Why is this happening?

This is the original image:
[image: Original Image]

This is the recovered image:
[image: Recovered Image]

Comment: Try converting to float before going to HSV and back. When your image is 8-bit and you go to HSV, **OpenCV** maps the 360 degrees of Hue into 180 degrees (i.e. there is a 2-degree Hue rounding) in order to be able to fit in a uint8. If your image is float it doesn't do that.